# How to calculate this integral contains modified Bessel function

Tags: integration, special-functions

$$  \int_{0}^{\infty}  I_0^3 \left( x \right) {\tt e}^{-ax} dx $$

where $ I_0 $ is modified Bessel function

Comment: Check the *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products.*

Comment: I checked all Tables I can find but didn't find the answer.

Comment: So, you are taking a Laplace transform?

Comment: For $a=3$ the integral equals $\frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{1}{24}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{5}{24}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{7}{24}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{11}{24}\right)}{16\sqrt{6}\pi^3}$. It is related to the return probability of a random walk on a three-dimensional lattice ([see here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyasRandomWalkConstants.html)).